# I need to get all <a> tags that have a particular CssClass using regular javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I need to access all `<a>` elements of a particular cssclass. I know how to do it using jQuery. is it possible to do it using javascript function, instead of jQuery.

What I have done so far is get all anchor tags: is there a way to filter by classname in the for loop below?

```
function something() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        //alert(element.value);
    }
    //alert("total elements : " + elements.length);
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` takes a general purpose CSS selector, searches any sub-branch of the DOM tree and works back to IE 8 (with CSS2 selectors):

```
// find all <a> tags that contain someclass as a class name
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a.someclass");
```

---

If you really want to go back earlier than IE 8, I'd really suggest you just get yourself a selector library that will do all the cross browser stuff for you and has been well tested and supports a good array of selectors.  This won't be the first and only function you'd have to deal with this on.  I have used Sizzle for this purpose and it is the Sizzle engine that is inside of jQuery, but there are also others.  You can always write your own functions starting from `getElementsByTagName()` and applying more tests to the results, but why reinvent cross browser work that has long since been done for you and, unless you get good with feature detection, you'll be doing it the slow way in modern browsers that have more capabilities built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')
```

to get all elements with a specific class.

In some browsers you can use:

```
document.querySelector('a.classname');
```

To query elements by CSS selectors.

EDIT: Pure JS solution that should work in "all" browsers:

```
function something(classNameToFind) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var classNames = elements[i].className.split(' ');        
        for (var j = 0; j < classNames.length; j++)
        {
            if (classNames[j] === classNameToFind)
            {
                alert('The element has the class');    
            }
        }
    }
}

something('test');
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pJ9Ys/1/

Comment: I guess this doesnt work on some old browsers, I am only bothered about IE 8, and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName it works only IE 9 and above

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but take a look [here](http://www.webmuse.co.uk/blog/custom-getelementsbyclassname-function-for-all-browsers/) (found through a quick search, so I don't know how well it works). It looks like jfriend00's answer might be what you want, though.

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function( classname ) {
    var elArray = [];
    var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var regex = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + classname + "(\s|$)");
    for ( var i = 0; i &lt; tmp.length; i++ ) {

        if ( regex.test(tmp[i].className) ) {
            elArray.push(tmp[i]);
        }
    }

    return elArray;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your loop:

```
if(elements[i].className == 'targetName') alert('found');
```